# RISCV resolving opcode

Tags: riscv, machine-code, opcode, instruction-encoding

I need help with understanding how to solve this problem in RISCV.
Provide the assembly language instruction for the following hex values:
Address 1000: b3
Address 1001: 0b
Address 1002: 9c
Address 1003: 41

I know I have to change to binary and that RISCV is little Endian, but beyond that I dont know how to proceed. I have several problems like this but I want to do the rest myself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear for me: are you trying to disassemble binary code by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, RISC-V is little-endian, so the word at address 1000 through 1003 is
0x419c0bb3, in binary:

```
01000001100111000000101110110011
```

First thing to notice, the instruction ends in `0110011`. This matches several instructions, see pages 104 and 105 in [riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/blob/master/release/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf). To further decode the instruction I examine the FUNC3 field in bits 14-12, these are `000`. I am down to a few possible instructions, `ADD`, `SUB` or `MUL`. I now examine the most significant 7 bits of the instruction, `0100000`. The instruction is `SUB`. The full decoding of the instruction is:

```
FUNC7   rs2   rs1   FUNC3 rd    OPCODE
0100000 11001 11000 000   10111 0110011
```

In assembler this should be `sub x23,x24,x25`.
To check the answer it is best to use an assembler/emulator.